# Spring RequestMapping on Root

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring, spring-restcontroller

I am new to Spring and have a little problem with API.

My Spring-Controller

```
@RequestMapping("/api/user)
public class UserController {

  @RequestMapping(value = "/", produces = 
  MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public ResponseEntity<Page<User>> getAll(
    @RequestParam("param") boolean param, HttpServletResponse response) {
    /* DO STUFF */
  }
}
```

How my JavaScript currently works (w

```
http.get("/api/user/?param=test");
```

How I would like to use it

```
http.get("/api/user?param=test");
```

But if there is no parameter I still would like to be able to call

```
http.get("/api/user/");
```

As you can see I would like to get ride of the "extra  / ".
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this :

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "", "/" }, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, method = RequestMethod.GET) 
public ResponseEntity<Page<User>> getAll(@RequestParam(value = "param", required = false) boolean param, HttpServletResponse response) {
    /* DO STUFF */ 
}
```

With the `required=false`, you'll be able to hit this method with `/api/user/` (without parameter).

You can also create two different handlers (one to support `param` parameter and another to handle `/`).